# Limit image to display one time in NgFor Loop

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a activity page I'm building and I only want the user photo to show one time per user in my ngfor loop. however right now the user photo repeats for each photo every time. I only need to show the user photo one time per each new user it loops through. 
So where it says item.opPhoto I only need to show that one single time per user or basically the useraccountpic div.

```
<ng-container id="followed-user-row"  >
      <div id="follower-holder" *ngFor="let item of FolUserPosts">
      <div id="act-avatar">
          <div id="useraccountpic" >
              <img width="60" height="60"src="http://localhost:3333/uploads/{{item.opPhoto}}">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="act-feed">
        <div id="act-col">
          <div id="act-item-box" *ngFor="let photo of item.photos" (click)="gotoPost(item.uuid)">
            <div id="posttitle">{{item.title}}</div>
            <div id="act-feed-item">
                <img src="http://localhost:3333/uploads/{{photo.name}}">
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div style="clear:both;"></div> -->
    </ng-container>
```

Here is my backend api call for this that I wrote as well:

```
FollowedUserPosts: async (_, __, context) => {
          let auth = context.auth;
          try {
              await auth.check()
              const users = await Database.table('users').select('*')
              for (let i=0; i<users.length; i++) {

                // Find users I follow
                const myfollows = await Follow.query()
                .where('follower_uuid', '=', user.uuid)
                .where('follow_uuid', '=', user.follow_uuid)
                .fetch()
                console.log(myfollows);

                  // Add profile Image
                  const photos = await PhotoUpload.query()
                  .where('belongsTo', '=', users[i].uuid)
                  .where('type', '=', 'userPhoto')
                  .fetch()
                  if (photos.rows.length >0) {
                      users[i].photo = photos.rows[0].name
                    //   posts[i].opFollows = user.myfollows;
                  }
              }

              // posts list from posts table
              const posts = await Database.table('posts')
                    .select('*')
                    // .limit(4)


              // loop posts
              for (let i=0; i<posts.length; i++) {

                  // user posted current post
                  const user = users.filter((value) => value.id === posts[i].op)[0];

                  posts[i].opFirstName = user.firstname;
                  posts[i].opLastName = user.lastname;
                  posts[i].opPhoto = user.photo;

                  // Add post images
                  const photos = await PhotoUpload.query()
                  .where('belongsTo', '=', posts[i].uuid)
                  .where('type', '=', 'post')
                  .fetch()

                  posts[i].photos = photos.rows

              }

              return posts


          } catch (error) {
              throw new Error('Missing or invalid jwt token')
          }
      },
```

Here is my Angular query for it as well:

```
 activityPosts = gql`
  query FollowedUserPosts {
    FollowedUserPosts {
      uuid,
      title,
      opFirstName,
      opLastName,
      opPhoto,
      photos {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: @Robert can you post the sample folUserPost data

Comment: not sure how to set that all up on stackblitz however I went ahead and added additional code from backend and my query in my typescript file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of the loop and check if the index equals to zero (the first iteration). If so, present the avatar:

```
<ng-container id="followed-user-row"  >
  <div id="follower-holder" *ngFor="let item of FolUserPosts; let i = index">
    <div id="act-avatar" *ngIf="i === 0">
      <div id="useraccountpic" >
        <img width="60" height="60"src="http://localhost:3333/uploads/{{item.opPhoto}}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="act-feed">
      <div id="act-col">
        <div id="act-item-box" *ngFor="let photo of item.photos" (click)="gotoPost(item.uuid)">
          <div id="posttitle">{{item.title}}</div>
          <div id="act-feed-item">
            <img src="http://localhost:3333/uploads/{{photo.name}}">
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div style="clear:both;"></div> -->
</ng-container>
```

Comment: That would result in the loop not working correctly at all. the loop pulls the user who the photo belongs too. so im trying to show the user photo then their last five photos in a single line. but what is happening is it is showing the user photo for every single photo they have.

Comment: yeah so that shows the first users photo then stops. doesn't show the second or third or fourth user. the issue i was having was the users photos were being repeated for every post photo they had originally.

Comment: @Robert in order for me to give you a concise answer, I need you to explain what the payload you're getting and what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I went ahead and added that additional information to my post.